# Loading values to array in data segment with assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, armasm

I have a function that receives a number from 0 to 10 as an input in R0. Then I need to place the multiplication table from 1 to 10 into an array in the data segment and place the address of the result array in R1.

I have a loop to make the arithmetic operation and have the array setup however I have no idea how to place the values in the array.

Mi original idea is each time the loop runs it calculates an iteration and it stored in the array and so on.

```
myArray db 1000 dup (0)

.code
      MOV     R0,#8 ;user input
      MOV     R11, #9 ;reference to stop loop when it reaches 10th iteration

loop   
       ADD     R10, R10, #1 ;functions as counter
       ADD     R1,R0,R1 ;add the input number to itserlf and stores it in r1
       CMP     R11,R10 ;substracts counter from 9
       BMI     finish ;if negative flag is set it ends the loop
       B       loop ;if negative flag is zero it continues

finish 
       end
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This looks like ARM with Keil's syntax/directives, which I think are similar to MASM for x86.  But it could be some other ISA entirely, so I might have guessed wrong on the tags.  I think if you don't specify a section like `.data`, the default at the top of the file is `.text` or `.code`, so your array isn't in a separate section or segment.  But you probably don't want to optimize by using an `add`-immediate with `pc` to generate the address in another register.  Anyway, use `ldr` to load, `str` to store.  Or for byte elements like your array, `strb`

Comment: This loop doesn't make much sense; you don't initialize the loop counter (R10) to anything, only R11 as an upper bound.  Also, `cmp` / `bge loop` would be the normal thing to do at the bottom of a loop for that comparison order.  Like a `do{}while(r11>r10)`.  Don't jump over an unconditional `b`.

Comment: Yes it is ARM, sorry I did not specify. Thanks Peter

Comment: How about going through a beginner's tutorial prior to asking such a primitive question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is on the right track but it needs some fixing.
To specifically answer your question about load and store, you need to reserve space in memory, make a pointer, and load and store to the location the pointer is pointing to. The pointer can be specified by a register, like R0.

Here is a [play list of YT vids](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLN5_vOAFBsJtNWkbHzVYZ972B8E8GSNG1) that covers all the things you need to make a loop (from memory allocation, to doing load store and looping). At the very least you can watch the code sections, load-store instructions, and looping and branch instructions videos.

Good luck!